# Like button on a website

Tags: facebook

I want to add a like button on my website that will allow the user to l**ike a page**

I can't seem to find any documentation on this. I simply want to hook it up to an anchor tag.

Something like

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/page/like">Like my page </a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/

Answer (score 0):

for like button follow that doc
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages/

for like button follow that doc
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/